# Button disabled but not grayed out

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have button which is bound to command to change the status from enable to disable.
when the button is disabled I cannot click on it (there is no response...) but the 
color of it are remain the same like before (like enabled mode),how can I it that
when the button is disabled to give it color like grayed out.

```
   <Button Command="{Binding Select}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=SelWindow}"
                        Width="125"
                        Height="26"
                        Background="#f0ab00"
                        Content="Run"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding SelectServEnabled}"

                        FontSize="16"
                        Foreground="#ffffff"
                        Margin="0,0,80,10" />
```

Comment: Did you override the style of the button somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all; make sure SelectServEnabled is defined properly.

Second of all; Commands contain a `CanExecute` method which change the enabled/disabled state of the button. Don't use `IsEnabled`, instead handle it in the CanExecute method of the command.

Third of all; as FlatEric said there is a high chance of style override (check your Theme folder or `Generic.xaml` or something like that, and check any style with `TargetType` of `Button`)

I've tested your code like this and it works fine:

```
    public ICommand Select
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(SelectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Select", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public bool SelectServEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(SelectServEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectServEnabledProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectServEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectServEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(true));
```

This is a simple command:

```
public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        //here you can change the enabled/disabled state of 
        //any button that bind to this command

        return true;        
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide example?